# SQL get latest date record

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2

I have a query that has the following

```
DATE                    ID              Name
---                     ------------    -----------
2012-02-07 11:24:53.000 00001-KK-12 Smith, JEN  
2011-12-28 00:00:00.000 00001-KK-12 Bearson, Matt   
2012-02-13 10:38:18.000 00003-KJ-12 Wick, Julian
```

What I need to do is to get the latest date for a given ID and then show the results

So in this case, it would be:

```
DATE                    ID              Name
---                     ------------    -----------
2012-02-07 11:24:53.000 00001-KK-12 Smith, JEN  
2012-02-13 10:38:18.000 00003-KJ-12 Wick, Julian
```

I tried to use the Top(1) with a group by on ID based but was not successful

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There are several ways to do this. One way is to use row_number. Its useful if there's a possibility that there's a tie on date and you want to arbitrarily pick one.

```
WITH CTE AS (
SELECT 
   row_number() over (partition by id order by date desc) rn,
   date,
   id,
   name

FROM
   table)
SELECT date,
       id,
       name
FROM CTE WHERE RN = 1
```

Another option is to use an ANTI JOIN (no aggregates no CTE) as follows but will return multiple results if there's a tie for first for a given ID.

```
   SELECT 
      t.date,
      t.id,
      t.name
   FROM
      table t
      LEFT JOIN table t1
      WHERE t.Id = t1.id
            and t.Date < t1.Date
   WHERE
       t1.Date is null
```

Answer (score 1):

You want to use [ROW_NUMBER() OVER](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186734.aspx). I was about to create a sample, but it looks like Conrad already did :)